# A difficulty with the notion of a uniformly accelerated reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, special-relativity

I have a problem in the book General Relativity by L. Susskind. He states that:

[image]

Why if we give all the observers the same accleration, the distance would remain the same in Newtonian mechanics while the distance to the second observer grows in special relativity?

When the observers are accelerating along the $X$-axis with the same constant acceleration, what is the coordinates of the second observer in the rest frame of the first observer in both Newtonian mechanics and special relativity?

I would really appreciate if someone could explain me this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when they are all at rest they all start to accelerate at the same time. But once they are moving their planes of simultaneity tilt so the they are all at different times. If you imagine that as a 2d spacetime diagram, they start all points along the x axis (ie a plane of constant t) with their world lines pointing straight upwards. Now imagine that they are all accelerated instantly to some speed. All of their world lines will now be tilted over in their direction of travel. And if you plot a plane of constant time for each of them, you will have a series of parallel lines rather than a single line passing through all of them. So now their individual phases of acceleration are all out of synch, and the effect gets worse as their velocities increase. Its related somewhat to Bell's rocket paradox, only in that the accelerating objects (rockets) are piloted to remain a constant distance apart in their instantaneous rest frame, which is a slightly different arrangement to the one that Lenny S is describing.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way to think this is using equivalence principle. For observers keeping themselves fixed above black hole's horizion, closer one is to horizion, greater the acceleration one need. If their accelerations are the same, then some of them start to fall into black hole and some start to escape to infinity.

This locally equivalent to observers accelerating in Minkowski spacetime. Therefore in the situation discribed by Susskind, you shouldn't expect the proper distances remain the same.

(When I say acceleration, I mean norm of four-acceleration, an invariant. )